# In Codeigniter The result_array is not return more than 2800 record?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter The result_array is not return more than 2800 record?? but i have 3500 records but i put limit 0 to 2750 the query will executed otherwise array not return values.  How to return the values?

```
$wsql = "SELECT ID, prod_id, product_family, country_name, factory_details, substrate, thickness, width_size, length_size, appearence, coating_type, laminated_against_PVB, bending, enamaling_and_or_screen_printed, contact_name, contact_email, contact_phone, contact_address, created_on, updated_on, ip_address, status FROM product_finder_master WHERE updated_on > ?";
    $res["sggrpf"] = $this->db->query($wsql,array($arr['last_updated_date']));
    return $res;
```

Comment: Did you tryed $result = $query->result();

Comment: You may want to expand your question with some code samples.

Comment: Maybe 2800 records is exact number by the specific query?

Comment: how do you parse it? if you fetch everything into memory you may run out memory, simple as thata

Comment: Whenever you've querying lots of records, they all end up residing in your ram, consuming it as a horde of hamsters. The problem is not the exact number, the problem is that this approach will consume all of your ram, you need to process records in small batches, usually not more than 100 at once.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the pagination for that. It seems you are using mysql which has limitations. I received the same error but for inserting more then 10k records at a time.

```
$cnt=0;
 $user=0    
 do
 {
    $user=0;
    $sql = "SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 999 offset ".$cnt;

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $devices = array();     
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $devices[] = $row['push_id'];
    }
            $message = array("title" => $title, "images" => $images, "description" => $description);
    $resultOfGCM = send_notification($devices, $message);
    $user=mysql_num_rows($result);
    $cnt=$cnt+$user;

}while($user>=999);
```

Please find the above solution

Thanks
Nishant